# Disabling keyboard click but retain dial keykad beeps

Tags: keyboard

I'm looking for a hack for turning off the keyboard click of SMS'ing, typing in IE, etc but keeping the beep tones for when I'm dialing in a number (when making a call).

I know you can turn off "key press" tones in settings but this is overkill as it gets rid of the dialing beeps too. I want everything muted apart from the dialing beeps. Unfortunately Advanced Config. app doesn't let you achieve this either.

I've got windowbroken unlocked & rooted device (Omnia 7) so have access to registry/explorer through WP7 Root Tools.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess muting your phone unless you are at the keypad is also not an option?

Comment: Tom then you wouldn't hear the phone ring ;)

Comment: @GeertvdC: I hear it vibrate up to a meter as well as in the pockets of my trousers, but that might indeed not work for everyone. Seems everyone uses it quite differently... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

The only option you have to remove the "key press" sound is as you describe yourself by going to

Settings -> Ringtones and sounds -> play a sound for: "Key press"

This will enable/disable both the sounds when typing on the keyboard as typing on the dial pad.